# Is my graphics card in use or not?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, 13.10

I have a Samsung Series 7 NP730U3E which is running [Ubuntu Gnome 13.10](http://ubuntugnome.org). This computer have an Intel Core i5 3337U an AMD Radeon HD 8570M on the inside. [Ubuntu 13.10 is said to have driver support for this graphics card](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Fully_Supported), but I am not sure whether or not this is the case.

When I check System Settings > Details it says "Graphics: Intel® Ivybridge Mobile" and `lspci | grep VGA` returns `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)`.

But `lshw -c video` returns

```
*-display 
    description: Display controller
    product: Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
    vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    version: 00
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
    resources: irq:47 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e40000-f7e5ffff
*-display
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
    version: 09
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
    configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
    resources: irq:46 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

What is the case? Is my graphics card is use, or do my laptop have undiscovered powers yet to yield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To tell if your graphics card is in use you must run the following command: `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`. If it says Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe, then it's using your CPU instead of your GPU. If it's says it's using the Intel GPU, then you'll want to disable that in the BIOS and make sure your video cable is connected to your GPU.

Radeon HD 8570M is a GCN/RadeonSI graphics card so you will want to go to AMD's website and download/install Catalyst 13.11.

Comment: `fglrxinfo | grep OpenGL` gives `fglrxinfo: command not found`
What should I install?

Comment: woops, meant glxinfo*

Comment: This is what `fglrxinfo | grep OpenGL` gave me, but I did not quite understand what you ment I should look for: http://pastebin.com/qfgMbVs2

Comment: It's glxinfo | grep OpenGL, not fglrxinfo. Your system is using the Ivy Bridge GPU instead of the AMD GPU.

Comment: (Yeah, i misstakedly pasted fglrxinfo now, but I ran glrxinfo in the terminal). Okay, that's a pitty. But it answers my question. Thank you very much! (I will open up a new thread on how to get the drivers to work correctly. Catalyst just breaks my computer. But that's not to be dealt with here.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe the AMD card is enabled in the BIOS. If it isn't then the Intel graphics adapter baked into the Ivy Bridge takes over. Would you mind checking that?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer, you should have enough rep. to post comments.  Please post these type of comments in the comment section to help keep the questions clean.